# Spring boot - JAxbException(jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of jakarta xml binding-api not found on module path or classpath)

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

[image: java version]I have a maven project (version 1.8) and java version (1.8). I have a task where I have used eclipse moxy ( jaxb implementation) for creating xmls. I also have the jaxb.properties file in the package where the classes are present.

```
jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

The pom of the project looks like below:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-alpha4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

This project is integrated into a microservice, as an artifact and the controller in the microservice does some unmarshalling and marshalling.
The pom of the microservice looks like below:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>XXX</groupId>
            <artifactId>ProjectX</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

This works perfectly fine in the IDE. I can see the result i expect.
however, when I go by the terminal and do a  `mvn package`and build the project, a jar is created in the target folder.

When I execute the jar, I get the following error:

```
jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of Jakarta XML Binding-API has not been found on module path or classpath. -with linked exception: [java.lang.classNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.ContextFactory]
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here? A beginner here

Comment: Are you sure that your JAVA_HOME variable is pointed to Java 8?

Comment: yes it is. Added the image as an update

Comment: There are some tips on how to solve this problem https://mkyong.com/java/jaxbexception-implementation-of-jaxb-api-has-not-been-found-on-module-path-or-classpath/
But it shouldn't occur on Java 8.
If you recently changed your environment variables they could be not updated in your terminal
Check the version of Java in your terminal with `java -version`

Comment: Thanks @absence, certainly helped